# Selenium (Python) error: element not interactable

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click on this particular web element from this site: https://www.milanofinanza.it/quotazioni/ricerca/listino-completo-2ae?refresh_cens

[image]

I have tried in many different ways but i still get the same error (element not interactable).

My code looks like this:

```
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mainbox']/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/button[4]").click()
```

The element is actually detected but for some reason it isn't clickable.

Comment: Did you want to loop through it or just a single click>?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible explanations:

1. The element you detected is not the element you think was detected. You're using a rather long XPATH, so I would be suspicious without external confirmation that you *really* selected the button you wanted. If the button you *did* select is disabled, then it will not be interactable.
2. The button might not be clickable through the same method that selenium's `.click()` expects. I am not familiar with `ng-` attributes, so maybe it's just a language localization thing, but I suspect that selenium may be looking for an `onclick` attribute.

My suggestions:

1. Instead of using a complicated XPATH, consider selecting by the inner text of the button. So something like this: `//*button[text()=Successiva]`
2. Instead of using any xpath at all, just call the JavaScript function that is referenced in the button: `getDataTableNextClick()`

Comment: How can i call the javaScript function?

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script

Comment: does not work thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='page-item']/button[.='Successiva']"))).click()
except:
    pass
```

To simply click on that element just look for the button with that text.

To go through 15 pages you could do

```
current=1
last=15
while True:
    try:
        if current == last:
            break
        current+=1
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='page-item']/button[.='Successiva']"))).click()
    except:
        break
```

Now this site is a little trickier if you want to go pass the 15 pages since the pagination doesn't disable the button.

```
current="1"
old="2"
while True:
    try:
        if current == old:
            break
        old=current
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='page-item']/button[.='Successiva']"))).click()
        current=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@class,'page-item ng-scope active')]"))).text
    except:
        break
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```